# How is "manejar" used in Mexico? As "to have"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, diferencias-regionales, significado, méxico

A few times when I was talking to some people in Mexico they used "manejar" instead of "tengo".

Did I understand them correctly and is this the case that "manejar" is used Mexico to mean "to have" **sometimes**?

Comment: I'm not mexican so i'm not 100% sure of it's usage, i do know that for money you can indeed say "maneja mucho dinero" to mean "he has a lot of money", manejar can also be used for driving a car afaik.

Comment: Well' if you're handling something, you've got it in your hands, so you've got it after all.

Comment: I agree with Brian. Please nylypej, include a couple examples of uses of "manejar" you have heard to help narrowing the use in question.

Comment: "manejar dinero" no es "tener o poseer dinero", más bien se refiere a "usar dinero".

Answer (score 3):

According to the *diccionario de americanismos*:

> [manejar](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=manejar)
>
> III.  1.  tr. Ho, RD. Tener algo, poseer. pop.

Mexico is not listed in the dictionary among those countries which use the expression, but that actually doesn't mean much. Probably the use of "manejar" as "tener" has become more popular in Mexico and the dictionary is still behind registering it.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like something commented on this [page](https://pulpogenes.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/manual-de-muletillas-y-falsas-afirmaciones/), where you can find the phrase

```
"Le vengo manejando..."
```

That is used by sellers to emphasize what they are selling and differentiating it from what everyone else is able to offer you.

So the phrase ***le vengo manejando*** is used instead of ***today I have for you*** or something of the likes.

Answer (score 1):

It is used alongside to have, you could interpret as "manage/managing"

```
Yo manejo cierta linea de productos
```

Can be stand as

```
I manage certain product line
```

or

```
I work with certain product line
```

Be aware of the context, because "manejar" also means to drive a machine/car/situation